# Does someone with a Turkish Resident Permit needs a visa to visit North Cyprus

Tags: northern-cyprus

I want to confirm if a valid Turkish Resident Permit can take you to North Cyprus for a visit?

Comment: In addition to a passport, or on its own?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold for now.